# Unable to connect with postgres in fastapi using docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am unable to connect with PostgreSQL in fastapi. I am using docker compose to connect both. I am using the exact credentials as shown below. So its not dummy one. I am also confuded whether the port should be 5433 or 5433 in psycopg2 code.

This is docker compose file.

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  smart_api:
    image: smart_api:latest
    build:
      context: ./smart_api
    env_file:
      - ./env_file.env
    container_name: smart_api
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - smart_net

  postgres:
      image: postgres:alpine
      container_name: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: sparkdb
        POSTGRES_USER: talha
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypass
      volumes:
        - sqldb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      ports:
        - "5433:5432"
      networks:
        - smart_net
networks:
  smart_net:
    driver: bridge
    name: smart_net

volumes:
  sqldb:
```

This is my fastapi code where I want to connect with database

```
@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    connection = psycopg2.connect(
                dbname='sparkdb',
                user='talha',
                password='mypass',
                host='postgres',
                port='5433'
            )
    connection.autocommit = True
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE sparkdb")
```

But I am getting this error

```
smartclinic_api  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 677, in lifespan
smartclinic_api  |     async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
smartclinic_api  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __aenter__
smartclinic_api  |     await self._router.startup()
smartclinic_api  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 656, in startup
smartclinic_api  |     handler()
smartclinic_api  |   File "/app/app/app.py", line 25, in on_startup
smartclinic_api  |     connection = psycopg2.connect(
smartclinic_api  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
smartclinic_api  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
smartclinic_api  | psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "postgres" (172.18.0.3), port 5433 failed: Connection refused
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
If i change port in psycopg2 to 5432 i got this error

```
password authentication failed for user "talha"
```

Comment: Note that the username/password on the postgres container is only used if /var/lib/postgressql/data is empty. If you have an existing database in your volume, username/password isn't used. If you don't need the data in the volume, try deleting it to create a fresh one. Then the username/password will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Change port to 5432. 5432 is Postgres port inside container and use it to connect between containers by compose network.
Port 5433 is to connect from your host.

Comment: i change the port to 5432 now i got password authentication failed for user "talha"

Answer (score 0):

This is not FastAPI blocking the port forwarding. When the services are in the same container, they connect through the default port. However, when connecting to the same database outside the container, you can use port forwarding.